# Sefardic transliteration scheme?

Tags: hebrew, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, transliteration

I am looking for a standard for transliteration of Hebrew for Sefardim, for the various nekudot and letters.

For example, how does one transliterate a כ with no dagesh? Is it kh of ch? How about ח? How are segol, sheva, and tzeirei distinguished from one another?

Ideally, I would like some published standard which is in use, and which I can point to.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8F_PW9P6dqlYTJmb0c2VnNtLUU naqqudhoth

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: There are dozens of these online already.

Comment: Where? Someplace standard, rather than haphazard? Don't know if on topic.

Comment: http://www.viceregency.com/Translit.htm http://www.jewfaq.org/translitguide.htm http://library.princeton.edu/departments/tsd/katmandu/hebrew/trheb.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Hebrew#Table from a quick google search.

Comment: @DoubleAA, So the SBL Handbook of Style (viceregency), I already have something parallel, as "Academic". The Princeton one seems more Yiddish / Ashkenazic, or doesn't provide guidance what it **specifically** Sefardic. Wikipedia, anyone can edit, and does not correspond to what I see in common use. I have my own thoughts, but it would be nice to have a standard in common use in print. Like Artscroll has a standard transliteration scheme, where kametz is usually 'o'.

Answer (score 1):

Some common ones are:

כ as kh while ח is ch.

ק is q while כ with a dagesh is k

Another is using ḥ for ח and kh for כ.

Then there's ṭ for ט and a t for ת

Seghol is e, whereas shewa na is just an apostrophe.

There are no real published standards. Everyone takes some of these, but not all. It's all a bit of a mess. Another great question is how do you distinguish between a silent ה and a mappik ה when transliterating into English

Comment: For transliterating final ה, as I, despite my use of Ashkenazis distinguish between הֿ and הּ, use ẖ for הּ and h for הֿ. When transliterating for academic work (when Hebrew is not an option) everything but שׂ and ס and תּ and ט have unique symbols.

Comment: i forgot to mention there is a Sephardic practice to put a ṭ for tet.

Comment: Any distinction between שׂ ס צ? I generally see all those as "s" for Sefardim.

Comment: Ḥ for heit Ṣ for saad

Comment: Thanks. Follow-up, what are your thoughts about this, choosing Sefardic? http://girsology.com/heb/transliterate.php

Comment: To make this work, needs for now to be Internet Explorer of Microsoft Edge (I tried on the latter) with e.g. the following text:
וּבְכֹחַ מִצְוָה זוֹ יִמָּשֵׁך הַחֶסֶד הַפְּנִימִי הָעֶלְיוֹן הַנִּקְרָא יוֹמָם, יוֹמָא דְּכָלִיל לְכֻלְּהוּ יוֹמֵי שֶׁהוּא הַחֶסֶד שֶׁבְּחֶסֶד מֵאִימָּא עִלָּאָה לְרָחֵל אִמֵּנוּ. וְגַם תְּקַבֵּל עוֹד רָחֵל אִמֵּנוּ הַחֶסֶד הָעֶלְיוֹן שֶׁבְּכָל הַחֲסָדִים דְּאוֹר מַקִּיף מֵאִימָּא עִלָּאָה קַדִּישָׁא, שֶׁהוּא הַחֶסֶד שֶׁבְּחֶסֶד שֶׁבָּהּ:

Comment: you can also use numbers like my friends and i use based on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_chat_alphabet#Comparison_table

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov  thanks, maybe I'll add it as a separate scheme. any name for it?

Comment: @joshwaxman yea arabizi by arabs lol